# Could not find method Properties() for arguments [] fails to run Android app with Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I need your help, for some reasons my app doesn't run on Android anymore, I get the following error :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Projects\myapp\android\app\build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method Properties() for arguments [] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 992ms
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I tried several commands :

```
flutter packages pub cache repair
```

and flutter clean but none of these work. For info here is my extension that I use :

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_auth: ^0.15.4
  provider: ^4.0.4
  cloud_firestore_all: ^0.1.1+4
  google_sign_in: ^4.1.1
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.6+1
  fluttertoast: ^3.1.3

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
```

I also tried to change in app/build.gradle : 
def localProperties = Properties() 
 
to
def localProperties = new Properties() 
But it didn't change anything, I'm running out of solutions from what I've found, the app still work fine on iOS.
Thanks for the help